# WPF printing multiple elements in the visual tree of a window

Tags: wpf, printing

I have a WPF window that contains three items controls, along with 3 buttons.  Is there any way using PrintVisual() that I can print just two of the items controls, and no buttons?

My first thought was to dynamically create a StackPanel and add the controls that I wanted to print to it, but I can't do that without detaching them first and it seems problematic.

I would like to use PrintVisual because it's so simple.  (Unfortunately I can't spend too much time on this application).

***Please forgive the lack of source code supplied, but I'm relatively new to WPF and currently my form is grotesquely over-coded.  I guess I'm just curious if there is a simple solution out there.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using a viewmodel for each item in the ItemsControl?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  This was my first attempt at a WPF application and I didn't have time to grasp all of MVVM.  Eventually I will convert it, but not for a while.

Comment: Is there any hope for me without using viewmodels?

Comment: You really should use viewmodels, I honestly can't think of a way to do it without that would not require mounds of code, I also recommend trying your hand at some test apps before jumping into production with a new language

Comment: @jimmyjambles  
I am probably going to convert this to MVVM sooner than later.  Given that, what would be the method to print the selected controls?

Comment: when you say print do you mean like out of a printer?  Or do you mean display?

Comment: Out of the printer.  I am able to print any one control on the window to print (sized to the printed page), but I need to add another ItemsControl to the print job, so they print together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is only printing a part of the page.  Place your two items controls that you want to print inside a Grid element.  Give it a name

```
<Grid x:Name="printGrid">
    ....
</Grid>
```

Then you can call PrintDialog.PrintVisual like

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintVisual(printGrid,"The Description");
```

If you cannot manage to group only those controls into their own grid you could do it manually by creating a Container in code and adding your existing named itemsControls to them.  Then you can PrintVisual the container.

Comment: Originally, I tried the latter approach of putting the controls into a grid control in code and printing that, but I was getting an error that the controls already had a parent and that I'd have to reset it.  
Your first suggested worked fine for me as I only had to move a couple controls around to isolate what I needed to print.

Thanks!